# Subsetting data frames in a list in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am working with ecological data.  I have a list with 10 data frames (ten different Taxa), each of which have 36 columns (id, species, taxa, weight, etc.).

I need to apply a filter to all of the data frames within my list, to separate by a certain character(herbicide, insecticide, etc.) in one of the columns.

I tried to do it with this code:

```
data0 <-subset(data1, TAXA != "Annelida" & TAXA != "Arachnida" & TAXA != "Fungi" & TAXA != "Mammalia" & TAXA != "Platyhelminthes")

data2 <- split(data0, f = data0$TAXA)

herb <- data2[data2[, "USEPATTERN"] =="Herbicide",]
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error in data2[, "USEPATTERN"] : incorrect number of dimensions

From there I need to count the number of times data has been entered for each df for the last 5 columns(NA, NA, NA, 35, NA, 45), which I am uncertain how to do.

Comment: Pls `deput()` some of your data so that we can work on it

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do this -

1. First `subset` then `split` -

```
data2 <- subset(data0, USEPATTERN == "Herbicide")
herb <- split(data2, data2$TAXA)
```

2. First `split` then `subset`. (Similar to yours)

```
data2 <- split(data0, f = data0$TAXA)
herb <- lapply(data2, function(x) subset(x, USEPATTERN == "Herbicide"))
```